# Search and replace on VSCode it's going wrong

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having a problem with search and replace on multi files with VS Code. As you can see, if I try search and replace a `<head>` tag in all files, VS Code select other string even I check **match whole word** and **differentiate uppercase and lowercase**.

Someone can help me to fix this?

*(the replace shown below is only to exemplify)*

[image: VS Code screenshot]

Comment: I see no wrong ones in the image

Comment: I searched for `<head>`, vscode is replacing `<html>`

Comment: very strange, it replaces `html` with `<heading`, it does not use the complete replace string, does this happen in a clean version of the VSC Insiders. I tried in a project with 50+ html files and it does not happen